# Is the integral of the probability density of finding a paricle symmetric about the mean?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, terminology, definition, probability, statistics

Is the probability density integral of finding a particle symmetric about the expectation value? Also is the probability integral symmetric with respect to standard deviations from the mean? Like if I calculate the probability of finding a particle to the right of $x$ plus one standard deviation, is it the same as the probability of finding it to the left of $x$ minus one standard deviation? $x$ here is the expectation value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the probability density integral of finding a particle symmetric about the expectation value?

No, not necessarily. Some probability distributions are symmetric and others are not (these are called [skewed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness) distributions).

One should be particularly conscious about the difference between the mean, the median and the mode of a distribution:

- *mean* is the expectation value, i.e., $$\mu=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x\rho(x)dx $$
- *median* is the value that the probability to be above the median is the same as the probability to be below the median, i.e., $$\int_{-\infty}^m\rho(x) dx=\int_m^{+\infty}\rho(x) dx$$
- *mode* is the highest point of the distribution, i.e., the point of maximum probability density (a distribution may have more than one mode - multimodal distribution).

> Also is the probability integral symmetric with respect to standard deviations from the mean? Like if I calculate the probability of finding a particle to the right of x+ one standard deviation, is it the same as the probability of finding it to the left of x-one standard deviation?

*Standard deviation* is a parameter of [normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution), i.e., of the distribution with probability density
$$\rho(x|\mu,\sigma^2)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}.$$
By the [Central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem), many repeated measurements of continuous quantities can be described by a normal distribution, and this is the reason why the standard deviation, $\sigma^2$, is frequently used to describe the spread of a distribution. In QM we often deal with distributions that are not normal. (Remark: the ground state of a harmonic oscillator is true normal distribution).

[*Kurtosis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurtosis) and [*skewness*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness) are quantities often used in statistics to described deviations from normality and asymmetry of distributions.